# Memory leakage due to SetBackgroundBitmap

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, wxwidgets

I have added a image (tiled) as a background to a class inheriting from **wxPanel**

Inside the constructor, the second line below is causing memory leakage, (reported in debug mode)

```
wxImage bg(_("images/textures/icobbg8.jpg"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);

SetBackgroundBitmap(wxBitmap(bg));
```

If i comment the `SetBackgroundBitmap` memory leak is no longer reported. 
Note - During debugging, and after viewing call stack i rounded on this statement.

Please tell me, how to overcome memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should call `SetBackgroundBitmap(wxNullBitmap)`
in your destructor

```
Class MyPanel:public wxPanel
{
   MyPanel(wxWindow* parent, int x, int y, int w, int h);
   ~MyPanel();
};

MyPanel::~MyPanel()
{
   SetBackgroundBitmap(wxNullBitmap); //set null bitmap backgrond, so not 
                                      //reference bg to overcome the leak
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved the problem, no more memory leakage!

Answer (score 1):

When the constructor exits, the wxImage bg will be destroyed.  However, the class still exists and the background image is still needed.

Try changing the bg from a local to an attribute of the class.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense to me. Will try it and see. Which one seems appropriate `wxBitmap bmpbg;` or `wxBitmap *bmpbg;`? Because both will work.